# Performance at serial read python

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am reading string from serial in a loop and realize that the processor is at 100% (RaspberryPI) while waiting for the next serial.read(). 
I found recommendation to add a few sleeps here and there, but doing this might cause missing serial data. In theorie I am getting a string from serial every 5 seconds, but could be a bit more or less and not in my control.

Is there a way to solve this in python better and with less processor use?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600, timeout=0)

def sr():
    while True:
        for line in ser.read():
            try:
                response = ser.readlines(None)
                response = str(response)
                print response
            except:
                print datetime.datetime.now(), " No data from serial connection."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sr
    ser.close()
```

Comment: In this cases you usually use [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/select.html). However I have never used serials, so I have no idea whether they are supported by the stdlib module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i remember (been a while since i used pyserial) i am sure that serial uses buffers, so as long as your message doesn't fill the buffer you shouldn't lose any data.

assuming i'm looking at the docs for the right module the following page:
[Pyserial docs][1]http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html

make mention about buffers both on the input and output.

so you should have no problems with putting sleeps into your program as the buffers will collect the data until you read it. (assuming your messages are not big enough to cause an overflow)

James

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot control the output side, as it is a black box. So I have no idea, if buffer is used. I can just consume the messages.

Comment: Are you using the pyserial module? If so the buffers are built in

Comment: I checked the serial module installed using dpgk and it is called python-serial.

Comment: that should be the module you want then, the buffer i mentions is in the software (in that module) and means that as long as you don't let the buffer overflow you can read from it when you want, leaving it a couple of seconds after the data is received wont make any difference to the programs performance (but should dramatically reduce the impact on the CPU), if you wanted to test this all you have to do is set up a simple experiment to send data into it from something you can control, and make the pi wait before reading it. just to be clear, you must have the port open for the buffer to work

Comment: Yes, it does increase the performance, but I am unsure how long I should wait. I have 2x time.sleep(1) in the loop. Looking at htop the CPU usage jumps between 8% and 100% pretty much 50/50 of the time. It is hard to believe the processor runs at a 100% just to read a single line from serial (about 230-300 characters per line).

Comment: well I would say it depends how time sensitive your data stream is, if its not, I would suggest that you have a total pause of around 4-4.5 seconds in there, as you will still be checking it faster than your repetition rate, but much less often than you could be.

Comment: Great, this helps a lot. I also used a timeout of 0.3, bringing load down a lot. Thanks for the help !!!